# What is this Icon Network Connection?

Tags: wireless, 20.04, indicator, postfix

This Icon Appear In My Pc (Ubuntu 20.04) And Now My Wifi Connection Doesn't Work,Someone Know How Fix it?

[image]

Comment: Its LAN Connection

Comment: why is this tagged 20.10 when you use 20.04?

Comment: Cause i was about to install an update but i was whithout connection

Comment: You have an ethernet cable plugged in, and Ubuntu has decided that it's a better connection than your wireless connection. If you want to stick with wireless, just unplug the cable.

Comment: Bruh there is any cable just usb keyboard and mouse am very upset  i did all tutorials 

Comment: Reboot the computer.

Answer (score 1):

1. This icon means that your route settings preffer the ethernet connection on other connections.

   - If there is no ethernet cable connected to your computer and you computer still trying to use that connection check those options:
   - static ethernet connection is set up, check it by clicking on ethernet icon->"edit connections"->if there is ethernet static connection delete him.
   - now reboot your computer and check if wifi is working.
   - if it is not working try step 2.
2. Execute the command `ifconfig` and look for your eth connection, it should be named as `eth0` or `enp0s3`.
3. Now execute the command `route -n`.

   - now look for your ethernet connection name under `Use Iface`.
   - check for your ethernet connection `metric` numeric value.
   - **The interface with lower metric is preferred for Internet**.
4. If the ethernet connection have the lowest metric value you can change it with `ifmetric` command.

   - install the ifmetric with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install ifmetric`.
   - execute the command `ifmetric ethInterfaceName numericValue`
   - for example `ifmetric eth0 1000`
   - **or just give a better priority to your wifi interface**
   - for example `ifmetric wlan0 0`.
5. If that is working you can reboot the computer to check that is stable.

   - if it is not stable you can use `crontab -e` to run this command as a scheduled task.

**if this solution not working please specify your problem by posting the commands output as and edit to your question so i could help you solve the problem.**

[image: commandsExample]

Comment: Actually, my connection in ipconfig called "enp0s..." doesn't show up in route -n

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my laptop got shut down while I was connected to VPN and after starting it again I was not able to connect to the internet and this LAN sign would appear when I switched on Airplane mode.

I just connected to the VPN from the VPN's UI and disconnected again. This solved my issues.

"VPN's UI" was the important part here as I had already connected a lot of times from the top right VPN option but that didn't change anything